# Leaflet - how do you get individual markers from a featurelayer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, jquery

In Leaflet, if I have a feature layer filled with markers, how do I get these markers back from the layer? I want to apply different popups to each individual marker, instead of the entire set. I can't find a method for this in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The docs are great, look at the LayerGroup part. There is a method `eachLayer` that does exactly what you want:

```
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  // do something with marker layer

  // layer.feature is probably defined, to create marker, do something like this
  layer.bindPopup(createPopupContentFromFeature(layer.feature));
});
```

You can do similar things if you create L.GeoJSON layer with `onEachFeature` property. See the great tutorials on LeafletJS web.

Comment: No, that seems to bind the same popup to every feature in the layer. I want all the features in a layer individually. The code example there, 

map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('Hello');
});

Binds the same popup to all markers. I need different popups for every marker in a layer.

Comment: You can do anything in the eachLayer(function(layer){...}) with each layer separately. As I suggest, your own function createPopupContentFromFeature(layer.feature) can create any popUp content you want based on feature data, that are unique for each marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting them all and then filtering, or using `find()` / `findIndex()`.

```
let found = featureLayer.getLayers().filter(…)[0] ?? null;
```